# Переход на Gulp v4 Перестал работать плагин сборщик спрайтов gulp.spritesmith

Tags: node.js, gulp, build, node-modules, gulp4

Перешел на новую версию Gulp (v4) и мой галп сборщик превратился в тыкву, Подскажите, как исправить что б работало как прежде? 

Мой package.json

    `{
  "name": "start-page",
  "version": "3.0.1",
  "description": "Start page for Andry's projects",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "gulp"
  },
  "author": "Zirka Andry",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.3",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^6.0.0",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-combine-mq": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-csso": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-htmlnano": "^0.1.0",
    "gulp-if": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^5.0.3",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.4.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-useref": "^3.1.6",
    "gulp.spritesmith": "^6.9.0",
    "imagemin-pngquant": "^7.0.0",
    "main-bower-files": "^2.13.1"
  }
}`

Собственно мой сборщик gulpfile.js:

/*********************************************/
/*DEPENDENCIES*/
/*********************************************/

let gulp = require("gulp"),// gulp coreconst //
    browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),// inject code to all devices
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),// sass compiler
    gulpif = require('gulp-if'),// conditionally run a task
    clean = require('gulp-clean'),// removing files and folders
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),// uglifies the js
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),// rename files
    useref = require('gulp-useref'),// parse build blocks in HTML files to replace references
    csso = require('gulp-csso'),// minify the css files
    cmq = require('gulp-combine-mq'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),// sets missing browserprefixes
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),// minify images
    pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant'),// minify png-format images
    spritesmith = require('gulp.spritesmith'),// create sprites
    htmlnano = require('gulp-htmlnano'),
    options = {removeComments: false};

/*********************************************/
/*BROWSERSYNC (LOCAL SERVER)*/
/*********************************************/

gulp.task('default', function () {           // start server
    browserSync.init({
        server: {baseDir: "./app/"}                     // base dir
    });
});

/*********************************************/

function buildSprite() {
    let spriteData = gulp.src('./app/image/sprite/*.*')
        .pipe(spritesmith({
            imgName: '../image/sprite.png',
            cssName: '_sprite.scss',
            cssFormat: 'scss',
            padding: 5
        }));

```
spriteData.img.pipe(gulp.dest('./app/image'));
return spriteData.css.pipe(gulp.dest('./app/sass/components'));
```

}

gulp.task('sprite', function (done) {
    buildSprite().on('end', done);
});

/*********************************************/
/*WATCHER (WATCHING FILE CHANGES)*/
/*********************************************/

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('./app/**/*.html', gulp.parallel('html'));          // watching changes in HTML
    gulp.watch('./app/sass/***/.scss', gulp.parallel('sass'));     // watching changes in SASS
    gulp.watch('./app/js/**/*.js', gulp.parallel('js'));           // watching changes in JS
    gulp.watch('./app/image/sprite/*.*', gulp.parallel('sprite'));   // watching changes in IMAGES
});

/*********************************************/
/*HTML TASKS*/
/*********************************************/

gulp.task('html', function () {
    gulp.src('./app/index.html')                        // get the files
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/'))                      // where to put the file
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());                    // browsersync stream
});

/*********************************************/
/*SASS TASKS*/
/*********************************************/

gulp.task('sass', gulp.parallel('sprite', function () {
    gulp.src('./app/sass/**/*')                         // get the files
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))        // add prefixes
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 7 versions'],
            cascade: true
        }))
        .pipe(cmq())
        .pipe(csso())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))                     // where to put the file
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());                    // browsersync stream
}));

/*********************************************/
/*JS TASKS*/
/*********************************************/

gulp.task('js', function () {
    return gulp.src('./app/js/*.js')                 // get the files
        .pipe(browserSync.stream())                 // browsersync stream
});

/*********************************************/
/*IMAGES TASKS*/
/*********************************************/

gulp.task('images', gulp.parallel('sprite', function () {
    return gulp.src('./app/image/**/*')                   // get the files
        .pipe(imagemin({                                // minify images
            progressive: true,
            svgoPlugins: [{
                removeViewBox: false
            }, {
                cleanupIDs: false
            }],
            use: [pngquant({                            // minify png-format images
                quality: '50-70',
                speed: 4
            })],
            interlaced: true

```
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/image'));                   // where to put the files
```

}));

/*********************************************/
/*FONTS TASKS*/
/*********************************************/

gulp.task('fonts', function () {
    return gulp.src('./app/fonts/**/*')                 // get the files
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/fonts'));                 // where to put the files
});

/*********************************************/
/*LIBS TASKS (PERSONAL DEVELOPER LIBS)*/
/*********************************************/

gulp.task('libs', function () {
    return gulp.src('./app/libs/**/*')                  // get the files
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/libs'));                  // where to put the files
});

/*********************************************/
/*EXTRASS TASKS (ROOT FILES, EXCEPT HTML)*/
/*********************************************/

gulp.task('extrass', function () {
    return gulp.src([                                   // get the files
        'app/*.*',
        '!app/*.html'                                   // except '.html'
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));                         // where to put the files
});

/*********************************************/
/*BUILD TASKS*/
/*********************************************/

gulp.task('clean', function () {
    return gulp.src('dist', {read: false})
        .pipe(clean());                                 // clean dir
});

gulp.task('build', gulp.parallel('clean', function () {
    gulp.start('images');                               // images task
    gulp.start('fonts');                                // fonts task
    gulp.start('libs');                                 // libs task
    gulp.start('extrass');                              // extras task

```
return gulp.src('app/*.html')
    .pipe(gulpif('app/*.js', uglify()))   // uglify js-files
    .pipe(gulpif('app/*.css', csso()))    // minify css-files
    .pipe(useref())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));                     // where to put the files
```

}));

/*********************************************/
/*MINIMIZATION JS*/
/*********************************************/
gulp.task('jsmin', function () {
    gulp.src(['./app/js/*.js'])
        .pipe(concat('common.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename("./common-xmin.js"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/js'));
});
// /*********************************************/
// /*MINIMIZATION HTML*/
// /*********************************************/
gulp.task('htmlmin', function () {
    return gulp
        .src('dist/*.html')
        .pipe(htmlnano(options))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});

Не могу понять почему, всё ломается на функции buildSprite() ? Что разработчики так глобально поменяли, что оно перестало работать.[Вот документация к плагину](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp.spritesmith) но её прочтения, что-то мне совершенно не помогает.

Comment: Я пользуюсь Grunt, не Gulp, но: // **1.** Уверен, что в Gulp тоже возможно запускать задачи по отдельности. Пожалуйста, создайте [**MCVE**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), оставив в Gulpfile только проблемный код. // **2.** Уверен, что в Gulp есть что-то вроде `--debug` и `--verbose`. Какие именно ошибки Вы получаете?

Comment: // **3.** Вероятно, Gulpfile также можно сделать [**более удобным**](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/tooling/supercharging-your-gruntfile/), разложив задачи по файлам и убрав over 9000 `require` ([**пример**](https://github.com/Kristinita/KristinitaPelican/tree/master/grunt)). // Возможно, поэтому с этим вопросом и не помогают Вам. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Перенесите задачу buildSprite() наверх, после default задачи. Туда же, после buildSprite, перенесите и sprite задачу. Ошибка возникает потому что задачи, описанные выше, вызываются ранее, чем они объявляются.

Comment: Поменял, только это всё ещё не помогло. Выбрасывает ошибку на функции clean при запуске gulp build

Comment: @BlackStar1991

gulp.start устарел и в gulp4 уже не используется, вместо него gulp.parallel
Попробуйте переписать таску build. Еще я бы посоветовал вынести отдельно uglify и minify в какую нибудь отдельную задачу

Comment: Уточню на всякий случай: 
gulp.task('build', gulp.parallel('clean', function () {
    gulp.start('images');                               // images task
    gulp.start('fonts');                                // fonts task
...

лучше переписать так: 

gulp.task('build', gulp.series('clean', gulp.parallel('images', 'fonts', 'libs' ... )));